# Authorize.net does not allow query strings for silent post URL?

Tags: recurring-contributions, authorize.net

We are unable to get authorize.net talking back to CiviCRM in regards to recurring payments.

In talking with authorize.net folks and they pointed out that query strings are not allowed to be used in the Silent Post URL: https://support.authorize.net/s/article/Why-Are-My-SIM-Relay-Response-Transactions-Timing-out-After-Submitting-the-Request

[image: query string dissallowed]

However, CiviCRM docs say for Wordpress you need to use a query string? https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/payment-processors/authorize-net/
[image: WP silent post URL]
We've checked the logs and see that authorize.net is not communicating back to CiviCRM. The transaction ID's for recurring payments are missing.

So who is right here and are people successfully using WP and Civi with authorize.net?

We have checked that are servers support connections via TLS 1.2.

On WP 4.9.4 and Civi 4.7.30

Comment: The documentation says http for the silent post url. Would that make a difference? I would expect that that should be a secure URL instead ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The culprit was the iThemes Security plugin. Here are the settings you should **disable** to avoid getting a 403 forbidden error that prevented the IPN from registering.

Under Banned Users

- Hack Repair Default Blacklist

Under System Tweaks

- Suspicious Query Strings
- Long URLs

I also **enabled** Enable XML-RPC under Wordpress Tweaks. I had encountered failed IPN's from PayPal before so I assume this would be wise to enable as well.